# Faild compilation standard servlet example

Tags: java, servlets

```
G:\demo3\src\main\java\com\example\demo3>javac HelloServlet.java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\lib\servlet-api.jar"
HelloServlet.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class HelloServlet extends GenericServlet{
                                  ^
  symbol: class GenericServlet
HelloServlet.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
                        ^
  symbol:   class ServletRequest
  location: class HelloServlet
HelloServlet.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ServletResponse
  location: class HelloServlet
HelloServlet.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                   ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class HelloServlet
HelloServlet.java:3: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
HelloServlet.java:9: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
6 errors
```

what iam doing wrong? CLASSPATH created to servlet-api.jar file btw
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hWkA.jpg)

Comment: this is not how you run a web application with tomcat

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the opener is not trying to run the application, rather *compile* it, as clearly stated in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 10 is using the new `jakarta.*` namespace for the servlet packages. You are importing the old `javax.servlet.*`. Just replace `javax.servlet.` with `jakarta.servlet.` and compilation should work.